# How do I rotate the "angle" or "perspective" of an image to fit inside of an object? (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

I'm trying to fit a flat, straight-forward image into the slightly angled iPhone below. I don't know the difference between perspective, warp, skew, etc. and I'm not sure which tool I should use to achieve this effect. I've tried to use wrap and while it seems like I'm on track, it just doesn't look right.

Thanks!

Here is the image of the iPhone I'm trying to put the image inside of:

[image]

Comment: Can you post what you're considering doesn't look right? We may be able to help you further and you would get better answers.  Are you just pasting the image over the phone and not considering the lighting effects of the image?

Answer (score 4):

I would say that skew is your best option because it can be used to create a slant.

The video on this site articulates the differences between the transform options quite simply, it might be worth a look for you.

http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/transforming-objects.html

"**Transform submenu commands**

**Scale**
Enlarges or reduces an item relative to its reference point, the fixed point around which transformations are performed. You can scale horizontally, vertically, or both horizontally and vertically.

**Rotate**
Turns an item around a reference point. By default, this point is at the center of the object; however, you can move it to another location.

**Skew**
Slants an item vertically and horizontally.

**Distort**
Stretches an item in all directions.

**Perspective**
Applies one‑point perspective to an item.

**Warp**
Manipulates the shape of an item.

**Rotate 180, Rotate 90 CW, Rotate 90 CCW**
Rotates the item by the specified number of degrees, either clockwise or counterclockwise.

**Flip**
Flips the item vertically or horizontally."

Good luck :)

Comment: What video are you referencing?

Answer (score 2):

Distort: it allows you to move each corner individually.